# How to force autofs cifs (samba) to use smb version >= 2.0

Tags: cifs, autofs

I'm using autofs mounting of a samba share from a Windows 10 (Creators edition).

Microsoft patched its OS to no longer accept smb version 1.0 sometimes in 2017.

```
SomeFolder -fstype=cifs,rw,username=johndoe,password=********,uid=root,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,noperm,noserverino,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm://servername/SomeShare
```

See [Mount CIFS Host is down](https://serverfault.com/a/842686/94260) for more information on the problem and solution.

After a while it finishes negociating (half an hour?) and then keeps working fine.

How do I do `-o vers=2.0` with autofs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option vers is ignored in, at least, Debian 8 (jessie). We had issues mounting smbv2 shares, even with smbv1 disabled on the server side and -o vers=2.0 set. 
I tested it on a Debian 9 (stretch) box and it worked. But you have to use the vers option. Otherwise smbv1 is tried and you can't mount the share.

Answer (score 3):

For example, you can use something like this:

```
-fstype=cifs,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770,nounix,uid=1000,gid=1000,vers=2.0
```

Comment: Could you expand the answer a bit to explain what it does and why the difference between this and the original is important?

Comment: I think vers=2.0 is being ignored. Actually, disabling SMB 1.0 in the Windows registry resulted in inability to connect at all. I'll do some more tests soon.

Comment: worked for me (with `vers=3.0`) on raspbian Jessie with automount 5.0.8